# How creating a report with dimensionFilter and matchType in PHP ? (GA4)

Tags: php, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use Google Analytics Data API v1 with PHP. I imported google/analytics-data with composer, then set up the whole API correctly and I get all my pages with the views. But I need to filter the results based on the URL with filters.

```
    $client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();
    $response = $client->runReport([
        'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
        'dateRanges' => [
            new DateRange([
                'start_date' => '2021-01-01',
                'end_date' => 'today',
            ]),
        ],
        'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
            [
                'name' => 'pagePath',
            ]
        ),
        ],
        'metrics' => [new Metric(
            [
                'name' => 'screenPageViews',
            ]
        )
        ],
        'dimensionFilter' => [new DimensionExpression(
            [
                'filter' => [new filter(
                    [
                    'stringFilter' => [new stringFilter([
                        'value' => '/orders/',
                        'match_type' => 'BEGINS_WITH'
                        ]
                    )]
                    ]
                )]
            ]
        )]

    ]);
```

**but how add a dimensionFilter** ?

```
"dimensionFilter": {
    "filter": {
      "stringFilter": {
        "value": "/orders/",
        "matchType": "BEGINS_WITH"
      },
      "fieldName": "pagePath"
    }
  }
```

The result is :

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: UnexpectedValueException
>
> Message: Invalid message property: stringFilter
>
> Filename:
> ...vendor\google\protobuf\src\Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message.php

Comment: Please clarify and re-word your question, right now it's not really a question. It will help the people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 12):

It works.

```
'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
  'filter' => new Filter([
    'field_name' => 'pagePath',
    'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
      'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH,
      'value' => '/orders/',
     ])
  ])
]),
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Make sure to include the files you need on the php file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression([
    'filter' => new Filter([
        'field_name' => 'pagePath',
        'string_filter' => new StringFilter([
            'value' => '/orders/',
            'match_type' => 'BEGINS_WITH'
        ])
    ])
])
```